# delete file after mongoose document expires

Tags: node.js, mongoose, public

How do I delete `file/image` from the public folder in a node js app, after mongoose document `expire` and is removed from mongo dB?

The file name is stored in mongodb document.

Answer (score 1):

There are no server-side hooks to get notified when MongoDB documents are removed via a TTL index.

However, a TTL index is just a date-based index used by a server-side TTL thread that wakes up every minute and deletes new documents matching the expiry criteria.

If you want to add some sort of on-delete hook, I would suggest writing your own expiry script and running this as a scheduled task via cron or equivalent. This script could first run a query to find matching documents ready to be expired, and then implement whatever notification your application needs before the documents are actually deleted

or you can use ttl redis (in-memory data structure store) check this [article](https://www.programmersought.com/article/523310198/) have pub/sub, and send notifacation after exipre time for a key